# aws lambda php runtime sporatically core dumps

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I tried setting up a php runtime as per the instructions at Amazon [Lambda Customer Runtime for PHP](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/aws-lambda-custom-runtime-for-php-a-practical-example/) but sometimes when I call it, it produces a core dump. Strangely enough, it's not every time that it does so. (it actually seems to do it within a minute or two of saving a change to a lambda script, and eventually when it starts working as expected, it won't do it again - however, it doesn't seem to matter how long I wait after posting a change, it will still occasionally core dump on the first few tries even after waiting a longer period of time)

I've tried different versions of php. I've tried different bootstrap files. I've tried increasing the memory up to 1024Mb (it rarely says it uses more than 50Mb)

How can I figure out why it is doing a core dump and/or prevent it from doing so?

EDIT:

```
Response:
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ExitError",
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: eb30f24a-ab2f-475c-8418-4dbb0bfeda15 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 139"
}

Request ID:
"eb30f24a-ab2f-475c-8418-4dbb0bfeda15"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: eb30f24a-ab2f-475c-8418-4dbb0bfeda15 Version: $LATEST
/opt/bootstrap: line 7:     8 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) /opt/bin/php /opt/bin/runtime.php
END RequestId: eb30f24a-ab2f-475c-8418-4dbb0bfeda15
REPORT RequestId: eb30f24a-ab2f-475c-8418-4dbb0bfeda15  Init Duration: 119.05 ms    Duration: 459.03 ms Billed Duration: 600 ms     Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 78 MB  
RequestId: eb30f24a-ab2f-475c-8418-4dbb0bfeda15 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 139
Runtime.ExitError
```

Comment: Let's start with "core dump."  What does that mean exactly?  Is there some output or error message you could share with us?  To me, a core dump indicates a PHP run-time failure due any number of issues like a double free or memory out of bounds and not a code or configuration issue. If AWS' past configuration track record is any indication, they probably screwed up their PHP server that is running your Lambda.

Comment: Honestly I don't know. The message says 'core dumped' and little more and I don't know enough about lambda to know if an actual core file was created somewhere or not.

Comment: example output added - line 7 of the bootstrap (a bash script) is where php is called. I have tried php based bootstraps, other methods of bootstraps, other versions of php including ones compiled by others. These occur shortly after saves then eventually it starts working. But since I am making ongoing changes to my scripts, I have yet to see if it resumes seg-faults at random later.

Comment: Exit code 139 indicates signal 11 (139 - 128) which is SIGSEV (segmentation violation).  This means that the PHP runtime has shit its pants and seg-faulted due to a binary error in the runtime.  There is nothing you can do to fix this problem, but I would recommend reporting it to AWS.

Comment: I just read the guide you posted, why are you building php from src?  I thought Lambda used a "server-less" architecture.  Use the package manager to install PHP and see if your problem disappears.  This could be caused by a dependency issue when building from source.

Comment: lol - love the explanation. All this tech is new to me. How do I use 'package manager' on lambda?

Comment: I am running into the same issue. @AlexBarker Lambda doesn't support PHP ootb. The guide explains how to create a custom PHP runtime as a lambda layer.

Comment: I see. @Scott, As I understand it you are using an AMI to setup a PHP lambda environment. To use the package manager, just start with the Ubuntu LTS (18.04 at the time of writing) AMI and run `apt-get install php7.2-cli` You will probably also need to install dependencies like curl.  Just add `apt-get install php7.2-curl` etc.

Comment: add where? And if I add them to a virtual server configuration, that won't also add them to the lambda environment. I compiled my own version so I could attempt to include all I would need, following the amazon aws instructions to do it. If those instructions are flawed or incomplete, that is my point of asking the question here, to figure out how/where.

Comment: The thing I am finding odd is that it seg faults only after an update for the first few minutes following that update. Once it starts working, I have a hard time generating another one.

Comment: All of AWS docs (and services) are flawed and incomplete.  It has been driving me nuts after every company on earth switched to AWS. You need to do the apt-get during your installation and setup process for the AMI / EC2 instance that runs your PHP lambda connector.  I have no idea how you are trying to do that. You could setup the AMI manually, use cloud formation, jenkins, teraform, the list goes on and on.  Personally, I would never touch Lambda for anything non-trivial.

Comment: OK, but the point being, it's not the package-version of the php binary that I am using in the lambda runtime. It's the one I'm compiling by hand. If I could get more info from the errors somehow, I might learn there is some library that needs to be bundled in the runtime itself. But It seems to be more related to some lambda environment issue in that it eventually starts working fine. As mentioned in the OP, it errors the first few tries no matter how long I wait before trying it. But after 4-5 failures, it then works ok.

Comment: i.e. if it was a missing library, it would never 'work eventually' - it would repeatedly fail without the necessary library. Meanwhile, if it was something to do with just a recent change, you would think waiting longer would mean it would work first try (after a longer wait).

Comment: in the meantime, we hired an outside firm to create a python based solution. But it would be nice longer term to have PHP to match our existing code base. Perhaps Amazon will follow through with their promise to include PHP in coming lambda releases.

Comment: I ended up writing my code to retry the lambda every time it gets back the `Runtime.ExitError` error. That'll have to suffice for now. Hopefully AWS will add their own PHP environment sometime soon.